# Is there a more efficient way to split columns

Tags: r, string, split

There are a few values that do not import correctly when performing this read.table:

```
hs.industry <- read.table("https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/hs/hs.industry", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Specifically there are a few values where the industry_code and industry_name are joined as a single value in the industry_code column (not sure why).  Given that each industry_code is 4 digits, my approach to split and correct is:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(hs.industry)) {
  if (isTRUE(nchar(hs.industry$industry_code[i]) > 4)) {
    hs.industry$industry_name[i] <- gsub("[[:digit:]]","",hs.industry$industry_code[i])
    hs.industry$industry_code[i] <- gsub("[^0-9]", "",hs.industry$industry_code[i])
  }
}
```

I feel this is terribly innificent, but I'm not sure what approach would be better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that lines 29 and 30 (rows 28 and 29, if we're not counting the header) have a formatting error. They use 4 spaces instead of a proper tab character. A bit of extra data cleaning is needed.

Use `readLines` to read in the raw text, correct the formatting error, and then read in the cleaned table:

```
# read in each line of the file as a list of character elements
hs.industry <- readLines('https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/hs/hs.industry')

# replace any instances of 4 spaces with a tab character
hs.industry <- gsub('\\W{4,}', '\t', hs.industry)

# collapse together the list, with each line separated by a return character (\n)
hs.industry <- paste(hs.industry, collapse = '\n')

# read in the new table
hs.industry <- read.table(text = hs.industry, sep = '\t', header = T, quote = '')
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can you explain the need for the collapse?

Comment: When you use `read.table` with its "text" argument, the text has to be a single string, not a list of strings. Thus we collapse the list of strings (each item of which represents one line of the original text) with the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to loop through each instance, instead identify only those entries which are problematic and gsub only those entries:

```
replace_indx <- which(nchar(hs.industry$industry_code) > 4)
hs.industry$industry_name[replace_indx] <- gsub("\\d+\\s+", "", hs.industry$industry_code[replace_indx])
hs.industry$industry_code[replace_indx] <- gsub("\\D+", "", hs.industry$industry_code[replace_indx])
```

I also used `"\\d+\\s+"` to improve the string replacement, here I also replace the spaces:

```
gsub("[[:digit:]]","",hs.industry$industry_code[replace_indx])
# [1] "    Dimension stone"          "    Crushed and broken stone"

gsub("\\d+\\s+", "", hs.industry$industry_code[replace_indx])
# [1] "Dimension stone"          "Crushed and broken stone"
```